# Is there a free Ubuntu unrar GUI?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm aware of the CLI unrar program but is there a GUI version of unrar?  Basically, I want to right click my rared file and unzip the content in the current directory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**[Xarchiver](http://xarchiver.sourceforge.net/)** is a GTK+2 only frontend to various command line archivers.

Xarchiver supports 7-zip, arj, bzip2, gzip, **rar**, lha, lzma, lzop, deb, rpm, tar and zip archives.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could try [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/), which is a port of [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try [PeaZip](https://peazip.github.io/peazip-linux.html). It has portable build without installation. It's [Open Source](https://github.com/peazip/PeaZip)